# JSON phasing with REST API

Tags: c++, json, rest

I am trying to read 2nd levels in a JSON file with the REST API's Json fuctionallity `#include <cpprest/json.h>`

I need to get from the following JSON the name field:

```
{"desc":"","id":"57681f5dc4864c821cc73bfa","lists":[{"id":"576973346263056c88cfe845","name":"Board info"},{"id":"57681f5dc4864c821cc73bfb","name":"Misc"},{"id":"576978294972d812e4a91580","name":"thing"},{"id":"57681fdc228443c3306cc762","name":"thing2"},{"id":"5768200b1fbf41dd2c974052","name":"thing3"},{"id":"57681feb72ca90abb3afe170","name":"thingy"},{"id":"57681f5dc4864c821cc73bfc","name":"meep"},{"id":"57681f5dc4864c821cc73bfd","name":"BannedWordsPhrases"},{"id":"57681fba60fdfbf576abaece","name":"Errors"}],"name":"READER"}
```

(lets call this file JSON1)
I can get JSON1["lists"] but not JSON1["lists"]["name"].

here is my code:

```
#include "cpprest/json.h" //how I am importing stuff
...

typedef web::json::value JsonValue; //all of these are being uses
typedef web::json::value::value_type JsonValueType;
typedef std::wstring String;
typedef std::wstringstream StringStream;

using namespace utility;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;
using namespace concurrency::streams;
...
int main() 
{ 
...
web::json::value J1 = web::json::value::parse(S);
web::json::value &J2 = web::json::value::parse(S1);
output(J2);
wfstream _file("jsonFile.json");
_file >> obj;
wcout << obj[L"lists"][L"name"]; // the broken line
cout << endl;
}
```

all the functions and variables work and are correct, it functions with out the `[L"name"]` and with `[L"lists"]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: my answer may be wrong, it would help if you could post the output of `wcout << obj[L"lists"];`.  Also, I am assuming you are trying to get "name" as in "Board info" and "Mics" and not "READER".  I will assume your output for `wcout << obj[L"lists"];` is:

`[{"id":"576973346263056c88cfe845","name":"Board info"},{"id":"57681f5dc4864c821cc73bfb","name":"Misc"},{"id":"576978294972d812e4a91580","name":"thing"},{"id":"57681fdc228443c3306cc762","name":"thing2"},{"id":"5768200b1fbf41dd2c974052","name":"thing3"},{"id":"57681feb72ca90abb3afe170","name":"thingy"},{"id":"57681f5dc4864c821cc73bfc","name":"meep"},{"id":"57681f5dc4864c821cc73bfd","name":"BannedWordsPhrases"},{"id":"57681fba60fdfbf576abaece","name":"Errors"}]`

**Proposed Answer**: `obj[L"lists"];` returns a list of 9 JSON objects in this case (listed above).  You can access these JSON objects by index (0-8).  For example, according to [cpprestsdk](http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1json_1_1array.html), `obj[L"lists"][0];` or `obj[L"lists"].at(0);`should return `{"id":"576973346263056c88cfe845","name":"Board info"}`.

From there you can get the name, for example:

`obj[L"lists"][0][L"name"]` should return `Board info`.